# PHP 8.0 no invoca al método __destruct() tras un exit()

Tags: php, poo, php8

Lo que hasta ahora funcionaba correctamente, al migrar a PHP 8.0, ha dejado de funcionar.

```
<?php

class Prueba{
    function __construct(){
        echo '<div>empiezo</div>';
        if(1) exit();
        echo '<div>hago alguna cosa más</div>';
    }
    function __destruct(){
        echo '<div>termino</div>';
    }
}

$p = new Prueba();
```

Me gustaría que el resultado fuera:

```
empiezo
termino
```

Pero, en PHP 8.0, únicamente muestra la primera línea.

Podría llamar a

```
$this->__destruct();
```

Antes del

```
exit();
```

Pero me gustaría que el script continuara funcionando en PHP 7.

Comment: ¿Por qué razón esto `if(1) exit();` debe existir evalúandose en el espacio donde lo colocaste?

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco mejor tu script? Parece un poco confuso

Comment: Hola@BetaM, era simplemente para ilustrar la dependencia de una condición cualquiera y que no quería que llegara a "hago alguna cosa más". Con `if(0)` el destructor funciona correctamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no se si será un bug o si se pretende que funcione de esa manera; ya que no encontré nada en la documentación de php en https://www.php.net/manual/ que hable sobre llamar al destructor desde dentro del constructor con un `exit()` ... pero creo, no estoy seguro que se aplica al igual que llamar `exit()` desde otro destructor:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2385581/4717133

> As the PHP documentation says:
>
> The destructor will be called even if script execution is stopped
> using exit(). Calling exit() in a destructor will prevent the
> remaining shutdown routines from executing.

me imagino que debería de decir así:

> The destructor will be called even if script execution is stopped
> using exit(). Calling exit() in a destructor or construct will prevent the
> remaining shutdown routines from executing.

ahora en la documentación de incompatibilidad de `php 8.0` dice lo siguiente:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php

> If an object constructor exit()s, the object destructor will no
> longer be called. This matches the behavior when the constructor
> throws.

que corresponde exactamente a lo que intentas hacer.

Pero Entendiendo lo que sucede realmente después de hacer alguna pruebas si se ejecuta tu código:

```
<?php

class Prueba{
    function __construct(){
        echo '<div>empiezo</div>';
        if(1) exit();
        echo '<div>hago alguna cosa más</div>';
    }
    function __destruct(){
        echo '<div>termino</div>';
    }
}

$p = new Prueba();
```

se puede decir que estas haciendo un `exit` antes de que se ejecute algo o que termine de iniciar el recorrido de php. mataste la ejecución antes de que terminara de arrancar

esto ya no es compatible la única forma de que funcione es si haces el `exit()` desde dentro de una Función/Método:

```
<?php

class Prueba{
    function __construct(){
        echo '<div>empiezo</div><br>';
    }
    function __destruct(){
        echo '<div>termino</div><br>';
    }
    function foo(){
        echo '<div>Hello World</div><br>';
        if(true){
            exit();
        }
    }
}

$p = new Prueba();
$p->foo();
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/81f993a7f23967085f7a1e12ff1c1a0285785818

Incluso después de investigar un poco en la pagina de bugs y soporte de php hay varios reportes sobre este tema y al parecer no piensan darle soporte nuevamente a lo que antes funcionaba:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79857

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80670

Simplemente cierran los reportes inmediatamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, @Francisco. Tu código funciona en sandbox y en PHP7, pero no el hosting de strato. Te pasa lo mismo que a mí :(

Comment: puede ser que lo ejecutes en php 7.4.13 después de esa version no funciona...

Comment: Haciendo un `echo PHP_VERSION_ID; ` muestra 80000

Comment: ya actualice la respuesta del POST recomiendo leerlo nuevamente: @DavidJP

Comment: Pues parece que no lo consideran un bug... curiosa forma de cargarse la retrocompatibilidad. ¡Gracias por el trabajo de investigación!

Comment: @DavidJP creo que te sobra la primera r en lo que le hacen a la retrocompatibilidad